vscode terminal in light mode glitches
I've recently encountered an issue where, whenever I switch my Visual Studio Code theme to a light mode (I've tried multiple different light themes), the terminal colors and fonts start glitching. This seems to affect both the color of the text and the clarity of the font, making it difficult to read and work within the terminal. Also triend with different fonts like jetbrains, fira code etc.
Here's picture

After tinkering a bit with settings i resolved issue with
  "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off",

Leave that here if someone encounters similiar problem in the future
